# OpenGL framebuffer resizeble texture

Tags: c++, opengl, cg

I'm using single color rendering in frame buffer

```
glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &frontFramebufferId);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, frontFramebufferId);

glGenTextures(1, &frontTextureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTextureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTextureId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, frameStride, frameHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, frontFramebufferId);
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTextureId, 0);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

When I'm resizing window it's gives me black color.
Resizing function:

```
glViewport(0, 0, frameStride, frameHeight);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTextureId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, frameStride, frameHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, frontFramebufferId);
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTextureId, 0);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

It's necessary to use glFramebufferTexture2DEXT function on resize event? Or what is the problem? I'm using Nvidia's Cg framework.